# Liquibase: mutli-line value

Tags: sql, xml, liquibase, multiline, changeset

I want to update a value (replace unencrypted with encrypted password) in the database that is two lines. For example:

```
some_random_characters
and_some_more
```

I've made a Liquibase `changeSet` like this:

```
   <changeSet id="1" author="KevinC" logicalFilePath="...">
     <update tableName="USERS">
       <column name="PASSWORD" value="some_random_characters
and_some_more" /> <!-- NOTE: Enter is part of the hash -->
       <where>USR_ID = '1'</where>
     </update>
   </changeSet>
```

As you may have guessed, it is saved as `some_random_characters and_some_more` in the database. How can I add a multi-line value to a database column with a Liquibase changeSet?
(PS: The DATA_TYPE of the `PASSWORD` database-column is `VARCHAR2(512 BYTE)`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XML considers whitespace as irrelevant, so you will probably need to wrap your data in a CDATA tag.

Comment: Thanks. I've changed `<column name="PASSWORD" value="...\n..."/>` to `<column name="PASSWORD"><![CDATA[...\n...]]></column>` and it works as intended.